# Signature of Methods Returning ModelAndView and Request Mapping by Method Name

Tags: spring-mvc

Two beginner SpringMVC questions:

1) Are there required signature types in SpringMVC for ModelAndView-returning methods, or it's free-form, with whatever params/order you want? I've seen these examples:

```
public ModelAndView action1(HttpServletRequest request);
public ModelAndView action2(Model m);
public ModelAndView action2(HttpServletRequest request, Model m);
public ModelAndView action4();
//etc.
```

2) Is it possible to have a RequestMapping by method name, not the whole URL? We have a URL, /test, that can be either /test?method=action1 or /test?method=action2 (similar to Struts).

```
@RequestMapping("/test?method=action1")
public ModelAndView action1(Model m)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: 1. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods. 2. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers. Reading the docs is a great way to learn any framework.

Comment: Just one comment: in that documentation, they have a Path variable, @RequestMapping(path = "/pets/{petId}", but that doesn't work for me, I get an error. The only options for @RequestMapping are consumes, headers, method, params, produces, value.

Comment: path exists since 4.2, and is an alias for value (i.e. path and value do the same thing): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--